# How to get the set of nodes based on a given CSS selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to retrieve the set of nodes based on the given CSS selector in jQuery. Its done in YUI as YAHOO.util.Selector.query(abc,root), where abc is the given CSS. I have to convert this into jquery.

Answer (score 4):

```
var nodes = $('.someCssSelector');
```

To make it an Array of DOM elements instead of a jQuery object with DOM elements:

```
var nodes = $('.someCssSelector').toArray();
```

---

The default root is the `document`. So the above selector will find all `.someCssSelector` elements in the document.

Css selectors can of course establish their own root.

```
var nodes = $('#someContainer .someCssSelector');
```

This will give you all that exist as a descendant of the element with the id `someContainer`.

If you previously selected `someContainer`, then you can use one of jQuery's [traversal methods<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) like the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to locates elements from that previously selected element.

```
var container = $('#someContainer');

var nodes = container.find( '.someCssSelector' );
```

jQuery has [helpful documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). The *Search jQuery* field at the top is a filter that will actively narrow the API for you.

Comment: hey,thanx,but,is it like,we don't have to consider root parameter here,as it is in YUI?YAHOO.util.Selector.query(abc,root)

Comment: @shaily: Root is the `document`. If you want to set a different root, use a selector for that as well, and use one of jQuery's many [traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) like the [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.